# Vim - relative tab navigation

Tags: key-bindings, tabbed-user-interface

Is there a way to make `gt` work in the opposite way of `gT` when given a count?  `2gT` moves two tabs to the left.  `2gt` moves to the second tab, but I would like to instead move two tabs to the right.  How can I do this?

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate, thanks for the link.